# Unable to Deploy the portia spider in centos7 using scrapyd deploy

Tags: deployment, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd, portia

I have installed portia and scrapyd.

Created new project using Portia web UI - all ok

I can able to see the project folder in `slyd/data/project/new_project`

Then I have copied the new_folder to some other different path for deployment.

Updated the scrapy.cfg file as follows,

```
[deploy:local]
url = http://localhost:6800/
project = stack
```

And opened a terminal form the new_folder directory, entered the following command to get the deployment location,

```
scrapyd-deploy -l
```

got the following error only,

[image: Error information]

Could you please help me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The program you used to edit the file added extra characters to the start of the file (Those characters being \xef\xbb\xbf, the UTF-8 BOM). If you remove these characters it should work.